# Run process in real time

Tags: php, process

I'm trying to figure out how to display output (and read input) in real time in a process launched by PHP on the command line. There seem to be many alternatives: 
`shell(), exec(), system(), popen(), proc_open()`

and it is not completely clear to me what are the differences. All I need is to execute a process, display its output on the same terminal where the PHP script is invoked, maybe read input and finally return to the PHP script flow when the process exits. Among the options I listed `proc_open()` is probably able to do this, but it seems overkill, as all I want to do is to give control to an external process and wait for it to finish.

There are some questions which seem related, but as far as I can see they are actually about sending the process in background (which I do not want) or displaying the output in a browser (which is not my case, everything is in a terminal).

Comment: Can you spec out what you mean by 'real time'? This will make a difference in the kind of answers you get. For instance, 'real time' in term of human perception is different than 'real time' in terms of a control system at a nuclear power plant.

Comment: I mean real time in the sense of user perception. The point is that for instance shell() will give all the output of the process together, when it is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pcntl_fork()` and `pcntl_exec()` like [this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pcntl-exec.php#70708)

Comment: This seems what I am looking for. Is there a way to do the same, but input a shell command rather than the executable path and the arguments? It would simplify things a bit.

Comment: @Andrea: I'm not sure if pcntl_exec() works with shell builtin commands. But if you want to do e.g. `ls` you can quickly generate a shell script (she-bang line plus the `ls`) with PHP, write it to a file on disk, make the file executable and pass its path to pcntl_exec.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this result](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#IYBiINXRm2E/trunk/thomas/siege.php&q=lang%3aphp&l=50) on Google Code Search can help. As far as I can tell it's doing something extremely similar to what you are looking for, including grabbing output from STDOUT and (potentially) giving input through STDIN.